# MIPS parser syntax error on line 1

Tags: mips

I'm getting `parser syntax error on line 1`.
The example blow is from the book, but it's not running somehow.
It'd be really appreciated if someone could help me with this.

```
.data
prompt:     .asciiz     "\n  Please Input a value for N = "
result:     .asciiz     "  The sum of the integers from 1 to N is "
bye:        .asciiz     "\n ADIOS!! "
        .global     main
        .text
main:
        li      $v0, 4      
        la      $a0, prompt 
        syscall

        li      $v0, 5
        syscall

        blez        $v0, end
        li      $t0, 0
loop:
        add         $t0, $t0, $v0
        addi        $v0, $v0, -1
        bnez        $v0, loop

        li      $v0, 4
        la      $a0, result
        syscall

        li      $v0, 1
        move        $a0, $t0
        syscall
        b       main

end:        li      $v0, 4
        la      $a0, bye
        syscall

        li      $v0, 10
        syscall
```

Comment: global => globl, but still getting the same error.

Comment: There's no syntax error in PCSpim (with `.globl` instead of `.global`). You haven't specified which tools you're using, so the question is impossible to answer.